# Order of iteration in Python in one-line nested loops

Tags: python-3.x

Consider the following code snippet:

```
cur = 1176
allowed = {1, 3, 4, 9}
r = [digit in allowed for block in divmod(cur, 60) for digit in divmod(block, 10)]
```

The above returns `[True, True, True, False]`.

I don't understand what the third line does. In my mind, it's not even supposed to work, since the first `divmod` would return a 2-tuple, which would be the first argument to the second `divmod`, and this built-in can't accept this combination of types, e.g.

```
divmod(divmod(cur, 60), 10)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for divmod(): 'tuple' and 'int'
```

What's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`divmod(1176, 60)` give us `(19, 36)`. These are then passed to the second `divmod` in the following order:

1. `divmod(19, 10)`  gives us `(1, 9)`
2. `divmod(36, 10)`  gives us `(3, 6)`

Then you're checking the new sequence to see if they are in the `allowed`:

1. `1 in {1, 3, 4, 9}` => True
2. `9 in {1, 3, 4, 9}` => True
3. `3 in {1, 3, 4, 9}` => True
4. `6 in {1, 3, 4, 9}` => False

So the resulting list is `[True, True, True, False]`.

---

The actual order of operations is this:

1. `divmod(1176, 60)` give us `(19, 36)`

   2. `divmod(19, 10)` gives us `(1, 9)`

      1. `1 in {1, 3, 4, 9}` => True
      2. `9 in {1, 3, 4, 9}` => True
   3. `divmod(36, 10)` gives us `(3, 6)`

      1. `3 in {1, 3, 4, 9}` => True
      2. `6 in {1, 3, 4, 9}` => False

Comment: Thanks! So the syntax for one-line nested loops `for a in iter1 for b in iter2 for c in iter3 ...` runs left-to-right treating them as outer-to-inner loops? That would make sense. Do you know where that's explained in the Python doc / tutorials?

Comment: @Josh Yes, that's correct. No, I unfortunately don't know where it is explained. I imagine there are tutorials and documentation of this if you search on "list comprehension multiple loops" or something similar.